# How to chain multiple fetch calls with Promise.all? Getting response.json is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, es6-promise

I'm trying to do multiple fetch calls in order to display certain data. However, trying to work with `Promise.all()` and getting a json response has not been successful. I'm receiving the error `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): response.json is not a function.` How can I change my method to be able to receive the data properly?

**Method w/ fetch**

```js
  const getFilteredComments = (filteredSightings) => {
    let filteredComments = [];
    // loop through filtered code and apply id to each fetch call
    filteredSightings.forEach(sighting => {
       filteredComments.push(fetch(`https://ancient-mesa-60922.herokuapp.com/api/v1/reports/${sighting.id}`))
    })

    Promise.all(filteredComments)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => console.log(data))
  }
```

**If I just console.log() the response**

```js
0: Response
body: (...)
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers {}
ok: true
redirected: false
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
type: "cors"
url: "https://ancient-mesa-60922.herokuapp.com/api/v1/reports/14"
__proto__: Response
```

Comment: Promise.all resolves to an *array*, which does not have a JSON method, but which contains responses that do. It might be easier to `.push(fetch(...).then(response => response.json()))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Promise.all()` accepts an array of promises and resolves to an array of results.  So, you can't do the `.json()` on the whole array.  You could separately loop on each of the response objects and use another `Promise.all()` on those results, but it's much, much simpler to just do the `response.json()` BEFORE you do the `Promise.all()` so the promises that `Promise.all()` is awaiting are the `.json()` promises and thus your results will be an array of JSON results.

And `.map()` works better here than `.forEach()`.

```
  const getFilteredComments = (filteredSightings) => {
    // loop through filtered code and apply id to each fetch call
    const urlBase = 'https://ancient-mesa-60922.herokuapp.com/api/v1/reports';

    return Promise.all(filteredSightings.map(sighting => {
        return fetch(`${urlBase}/${sighting.id}`).then(resp => resp.json());
    }));
  }
```